# Sending an email verification after registering

Tags: php, sql, email, verification

I want, that users who register on my site, have to activate their account first, before using it. The problem is, that I don't get any email to my email test account.

Before I start posting a code, could the problem be, that I'm working currently on a local machine with xampp?

Otherwise, here is the code snippet

```
$random = substr(number_format(time() * rand(),0,'',''),0,10);
    $insertMailVerify = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO mailverify (mailAddress, token, datetime) VALUES (:mailAddress, :token, :date)");
    $insertMailVerify->execute(array(':mailAddress'=>$emailAddress,
                                     ':token'=>$random,
                                     ':date'=>$date));

    $to = $emailAddress;
    $subject = "Activating your Account";
    $body = "Hi, in order to activate your account please visit http://localhost/FinalYear/activation.php?email=".$emailAddress." and fill in the verification code $random";
    if(mail($to, $subject, $body))
    {
        echo ("<p>Message success</p>");
    }
    else {
        echo ("<p>Message fail</p>");
    }
```

Just in case you wonder where i take $emailAddress from: This is just a code snippet, i already let the software echo the email address, and it's correct. It even goes in the "Message success" if case, but I still can't get any email. What could be the problem?

Comment: on what address are you trying to send an email? something like Gmail? if so then you need to configure ISP configuration on your php.ini

Comment: Yes it is gmail, can you send me a link where to do this? Would help really !

Answer (score 6):

After submit the form you can use a code or link and send it to the user email id

```
$message = "Your Activation Code is ".$code."";
$to=$email;
$subject="Activation Code For Talkerscode.com";
$from = 'your email';
$body='Your Activation Code is '.$code.' Please Click On This link <a href="verification.php">Verify.php?id='.$db_id.'&code='.$code.'</a>to activate  your account.';
$headers = "From:".$from;
mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);

echo "An Activation Code Is Sent To You Check You Emails";
```

Code from TalkersCode.com for complete tutorial visit http://talkerscode.com/webtricks/account-verification-system-through-email-using-php.php

Answer (score 0):

in local host i think the best way is using `phpmailer` and `gmail` account

here the tutorial : http://www.web-development-blog.com/archives/send-e-mail-messages-via-smtp-with-phpmailer-and-gmail/

Answer (score 0):

It seems your mail server **SMTP** is not configured correctly....

check the port and IP of SMTP server address.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change you `PHP.ini` file like this and tell me if it works.

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP =  smtp.gmail.com

; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 465 //if 465 is not working then try 25
```

If this is not working then there are a lot of tutorials of how to achieve what you are trying to do.
Here is one link: [Send email from localhost](http://www.websnippetz.com/php/send-email-from-xampp-localhost/)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, but on linux.

1) Assuming your mail() function is working properly: the problem could be, that email is coming into spam-box (because these localhost mail systems are often marked as spambots, so email services are protecting emails from unverified host).

2) If mail() is not working, its not configured properly, if you follow some tutorial and configure it, which needs like 5 minutes, you will realise why not to use it:)

The best way for you is to use some free or paid smtp service. Very easy, quick and your emails wont be marked as spam. And install PEAR library to send email. Here is an example.

```
$from    = 'from@domain.com';
$to      = 'to@domain.com';
$subject = 'subject';
$body    = 'Hello!';

$host = 'smtpserver.com';
$port = '25';
$username = 'yourlogin';
$password = 'yourpass';

$headers = array ('From' => $from, 'To' => $to, 'Subject' => $subject);
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array ('host' => $host, 'port' => $port, 'auth' => true, 'username' => $username, 'password' => $password));

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

if(PEAR::isError($mail)) {
  echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
} else {
  echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
}
```

To your verification code: instead of telling user to write down the verification code, better generate him the link, that he clicks his account gets activated. Something like

```
http://localhost/FinalYear/activation.php?email=some@email.com&token=79054025255fb1a26e4bc422aef54eb4
```

on registration page: generate the activation token like `md5($email . '_sometext');`

on activation page `if(md5($_GET['email'] . '_sometext') == $_GET['token']) { activate.. }`

please note, that it is just an example, there are 10 ways how it could be done :)

Comment: why not use mail()?